# Scala search and replace using replace not giving expected results

Tags: string, scala, replace

Below replace function is not doing what i expected. what's the best way to search/match exact string from start to end and replace.
How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
val valSet = Seq("BELL","BELL.*")

scala> var str = "(((( EMP = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL)) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = BELL.*)))"

scala> valSet.map { x=> str= str.replace(x , """""""+x+""""""") }

scala> str
res1: String = (((( EMP = "BELL") OR ( LASTNAME = "BELL") OR ( LASTNAME = "BELL")) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = "BELL".*)))
```

Expected output is:

```
(((( EMP = "BELL") OR ( LASTNAME = "BELL") OR ( LASTNAME = "BELL")) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = "BELL.*")))
```

Comment: Question: how should an already quoted BELL or BELL.* be handled?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, where one wants to do search and replace on exact strings where one of the strings is a substring of the other (BELL is a prefix of BELL.*) the approach that one would use otherwise (str.replace) is not always going to work (if none of the strings is a substring of the replacement string for another string, one can make it work by doing the search & replaces in a proper order).

However, one can do this with regexes:

```
val str = "(((( EMP = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL)) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = BELL.*)))"
val regex = "BELL((\\.)(\\*))?"
val replaced = str.replaceAll(regex, "\"BELL$2\"")
```

If you want to prevent a "BELL" that's already been quoted, e.g.

```
val str = """(((( EMP = "BELL") OR ( LASTNAME = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL)) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = BELL.*)))"""
```

Then the regex and replacement become:

```
val regex = """([^"])BELL((\\.)(\\*))?([^"])"""
val replaced = str.replaceAll(regex, """$1"BELL$2"$5""")
```

(though note that this approach is a little fragile: if you want to handle quotes and ensure that they get properly balanced, etc., you're basically out of the realm of regular expressions and into the realm of context-free grammars...)